# Sitefinity Custom Checkout with Custom Shipping Method

Tags: c#, telerik, e-commerce, sitefinity

I have a custom checkout method. I also have a custom shipping method.

I have ripped all my custom code out and straight up copied and pasted the custom shipping method files found on Sitefinity's documentation:

http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/documentationarticles/developers-guide/sitefinity-essentials/modules/ecommerce/creating-a-custom-shipping-carrier-provider

and

http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/shipping-provider-model

Following this documentation I am able to create a new shipping method in my ecommerce back end and select my custom shipping method.

I have the following code that sets my checkout state shipping method id to my custom shipping method's id. The same for my cart order:

```
CheckoutState checkoutState = new CheckoutState()
{
    ...
    ShippingMethodId = shippingManager.GetShippingMethods().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "custom-shipping").Id,
    ShippingMethodName = shippingManager.GetShippingMethods().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "custom-shipping").Name,
    ...
}
```

and

```
cartOrder.ShippingMethodId = shippingManager.GetShippingMethods().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "custom-shipping").Id;
```

Works fine and dandy. Gets the shipping method. This shipping method contains the custom shipping carrier ID I defined while following along with the documentation. The carrier has 2 shipping service settings I added. I am also able to query them using:

```
var shippingCarrierInfo = shippingManager.GetShippingCarrierSetting("custom-shipping");
List<ShippingServiceSettings> services = shippingManager.GetShippingServiceSettings().Where(
                                                x => x.ShippingCarrierName == shippingCarrierInfo.Name &&
                                                x.IsActive == true).ToList();
```

and I get no nulls or empties or anything. All information as expected.

I go to get my shipping responses from my service by doing this:

```
List<IShippingResponse> shippingResponses = processShipping.GetApplicableShippingMethods(checkoutState, cartOrder).ToList();
```

This throws a lovely generic error message:

Null Reference Exception
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Of course I can't look at what they are saying is null. But I get a stack trace of the method that it is error out on.

trace:

```
at Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Shipping.ShippingManager.GetShippingCarrierProvider(Guid shippingMethodId)
at Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.Shipping.Business.OnlineShippingMethodRetriever.GetApplicableShippingMethods(CheckoutState checkoutState, CartOrder cartOrder)
at Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Ecommerce.BusinessServices.Shipping.Implementations.EcommerceShippingMethodService.GetApplicableShippingMethods(CheckoutState checkoutState, CartOrder cartOrder)
at SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers.CheckoutController.RunCheckout(CheckoutForm CheckoutForm, User user, SitefinityProfile profile, CartOrder cartOrder, String paymentMethod) in c:\clients\badder ruter\RiverValleyDairySF\RiverValleyDairy\Mvc\Controllers\CheckoutController.cs:line 600
at SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers.CheckoutController.ProcessPayment(CheckoutForm CheckoutForm) in c:\clients\badder ruter\RiverValleyDairySF\RiverValleyDairy\Mvc\Controllers\CheckoutController.cs:line 210
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

I am at loss of what I need to do. This has been a back and forth with a support ticket on their end for about 3.5 weeks now. Angry clients and all I need to figure out a way for this to work. Like I said straight copy and paste from documentation. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Maybe you should try to make your shipping method "offline".
Otherwise Sitefinity will try to call some webservices (not sure about the exact workflow) to determine which methods are aplicable for the current order based on weight / other shipping rules you may have set. As far as I understand - an online shipping method is a method that will be checked against a web service and an offline shipping method is a method that will be evaluated in Sitefinity based on the rules you added in the eCommerce admin.

Comment: Go to the Sitefinity administration, ECommerce => Shipping methods.
Find your shipping method and click Actions => Edit properties.
Find the "Shipping method type" and make sure "Custom (Offline)" is selected instead Standard (Shipping carriers).
You should of course also check "This method is active" but I guess you already did that. Also - you will probably want to define some rules in the Shipping price section so your shipping method is found based on the rules you specified and the order.

Comment: Unfortunately an offline shipping method isn't what I am looking for. I am using an external service to calculate shipping which is why I needed to make my own custom method to being with.